# How to make the FlashLight blink?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to turn on and off the flashlight:

```
func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        else {return}

    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if on == true {
                device.torchMode = .on
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .off
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Torch could not be used")
        }
    } else {
        print("Torch is not available")
    }
}
```

I want to make it blink until I press a button. How can I make it?

Comment: You could use a timer to make the torch toggle every second (or whatever duration required). Use a flag to check if the button has been pressed and invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var btnNotPressed = true

func blink() {

 if device.hasTorch {
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()

        if on == true {
            device.torchMode = .on
        } else {
            device.torchMode = .off
        }
        // toggle on
        on = !on
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
       // delay until flash shows/hides you can make it 0.5 if you it more fast
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 1 ) {
         if btnNotPressed {
           self.blink()
         }
       }

    } catch {
        print("Torch could not be used")
    }
  } else {
    print("Torch is not available")
  }
}
```

then set `btnNotPressed` when button is pressed